# how to get file info without submitting the form

Tags: php, filenames

I want to get the info of the file that the user has chosen. I want to change the profile image instantly without submitting. In PHP, there is the global variable $_FILE which gives you all the info about the file.

```
$(function() {
            $("input:file").change(function (){
               <?php

                $file = $_FILES['file'];
                $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
                $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

               ?>
             });
 });
```

Here is the code in PHP, but it doesn't work because the page has to be submitted in order to have the $_FILE variable.

Comment: Since PHP runs on the server not the client, this is a JavaScript question.  Did you search on doing this in JavaScript not PHP?  Also, the client has no idea what temp file name will be  chosen, and the file won't be uploaded until you do submit.

Comment: yes i search on how to it with javascript but got nothing. I am asking on how to do something that i have seen on instagram. When you choose a new profile photo, this one is directly submitted and you can see that your profile picture has changed without clicking on any other button except the button to select your profile photo.

Comment: That sounds like the page is using AJAX to do a submit, which runs PHP or other code on the server.  Read up on AJAX.